# how to render alphabets in 2D using threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js, rendering, text-rendering

I'm making a 2d game, where blocks are falling down ( tetris style). I need to render alphabets on these blocks. This is how I am creating blocks:

```js
 var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( this.BLOCK_WIDTH, this.BLOCK_WIDTH, 4 );
 var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );

 this.blocks = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < rows * columns; i++) {
  cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
  cube.visible = false;
  cube.letter = letterGenerator.getNextLetter();
  this.blocks[i] = cube;

  scene.add( this.blocks[i] );
 };
```

As you can see, all blocks will look exactly alike except for the fact, that they will have a different alphabet associated with them. In my update(), I move the block, left/right or down. When I do so, block position will be updated and obviously the alphabet should be rendered accordingly.

How should I go about rendering alphabets on these blocks ?

EDIT: I am using WebGLRenderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the screen position of each block (your "cube" variable above) that you want to paint text on and use HTML to paint text at that screen location over each block.  Using HTML to make a text sprite like this is discussed here:

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1321

You can get the screen position for your "cube" above like so:

```
var container = document.getElementById("idcanvas");
var containerWidth = container.clientWidth;
var containerHeight = container.clientHeight;
var widthHalf = containerWidth / 2, heightHalf = containerHeight / 2;
var locvector = new THREE.Vector3();
locvector.setFromMatrixPosition(cube.matrixWorld);
locvector.project(your_camera); //returns center of mesh
var xpos = locvector.x = (locvector.x * widthHalf) + widthHalf; //convert to screen coordinates
var ypos = locvector.y = -(locvector.y * heightHalf) + heightHalf;
```

You'll have to update the HTML for cube movement.

Another approach is to create specific textures with the text you want and apply each texture as a material to the appropriate cube.

Comment: not sure if it is a relevant question, but I'll ask anyways: Will the HTML approach also work with `WebGLRenderer` ?

Comment: Also, won't it be more performant to render to texture and apply that (since this will be done through GPU) ?

Comment: @brainy dexter   Using an HTML <div> will work with a WebGLRenderer.  You can position the <div> on the screen over the <canvas> that the renderer is painting.  If you have just a few letters that you want to apply, then textures would likely be easier to code.  If you have a lot of dynamically changing text, the HTML approach will probably be easier to code.  Performance will be platform dependent, but I personally have seen minimal performance drain from using HTML this way with THREE.